# How to store the intermediate results of a scala match expression into a list?

Tags: scala

I have a list of integer as input and i would like to store the intermediate result of every comparison in a scala match expression into a ListBuffer.How can i achieve that?
Below is the code that i have written.Currently i am only able to store the result of last comparison not the intermediate ones.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    var stor = ListBuffer[String]()
    val inpLst = List(1, 2, 2, 2, 1)
    for (i <- inpLst) {
      stor = i match {
        case 1 => "ok"
        case 2 => "notok"
      }
    }
    println(stor)
  }
}
```

This is the output that i want.

```
opList = List("ok","notok","notok',"notok","ok")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Mario Galic's answer is quite good way of approach to your problem, if you still insist on writing in your own way, below is the way to do it.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

val inpLst = List(1,2,2,2,1)
val stor = ListBuffer.empty[String]

for (i <- inpLst) {
  val str = i match {
    case 1 => "ok"
    case 2 => "notOk"
  }
  stor += str
}

println(stor)
```

This outputs below:

```
ListBuffer(ok, notOk, notOk, notOk, ok)
```

Comment: oh ok,i just needed to append the intermediate result in a ListBuffer.Thanks for the help

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using `ListBuffer` consider mapping over a `List` like so

```
l.map {
  case 1 => "ok"
  case 2 => "notok"
  case _ => "unknown"
}
```

which outputs

```
res0: List[String] = List(ok, notok, notok, notok, ok)
```

Applying Krzysztof's suggestion, we could omit `case _ => "unknown"` if we use `collect` like so

```
List(1,2,3).collect {
  case 1 => "ok"
  case 2 => "notok"
}
```

which outputs

```
res1: List[String] = List(ok, notok)
```

Comment: Instead of using `map` with default match, you could use `collect` with partial function. Then it will just omit unmatched elements.

Comment: @Mario Galic Actually I needed to store the intermediate results of every comparison in the match expression.Thanks anyway.

Comment: @GuravGupta What is wrong with using `map`? That is also storing the results of every comparison.

Comment: @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez No issue with map,the same result could have been easily achieved using map but i wanted to store intermediate results in match expression itself.

Comment: @GauravGupta What do you mean with _"in match expression itself"_? And why does that matter? **mutability** is a code smell, and should be avoided unless really necessary _(usually for performance reasons)_, but in this case it doesn't feel necessary at all. Cary to share your real use case to understand why you need that?

Comment: @ Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez  P07 (**) Flatten a nested list structure.
Example:
scala> flatten(List(List(1, 1), 2, List(3, List(5, 8))))
res0: List[Any] = List(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8)

Comment: @ Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez  That was the problem i was trying to solve.I already had done that using map,flatmap.Was trying to solve it using scala match expression just out of curiosity.

Comment: @GauravGupta Uhm, so you have a **List** either of **Ints** or other **Lists** of either **Ints** or ... - And you want to flatten all that. Well the result type of **Any** is a code smell, and I wonder that your solution using **pattern matching** _(`match`)_ is also unsafe due erasure. If you want feel free to open a new question explaining all your problem, especially why you end up with such kind of data.

Comment: @ Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez what do you mean by "the result type of Any is a code smell" and "your solution using pattern matching (match) is also unsafe due erasure".I am kind of stating with scala so would be a great help if you can elaborate?

Comment: @GauravGupta as you can see on your comment, the result of the function is of type `List[Any]` that is a code smell, every time you see **Any** you are probably doing something wrong. Also, I would suspect your solution does something like `case list: List[Int] => ...` due **type erasure** _(which is a **JVM** feature, you can search on Google for more information)_ that is unsafe, since at runtime, there is not way of knowing if something is of type `List[Int]` it can only check that it is an instance of the class `List`. - it would be better to just ask a new question with all the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to convert list into "ok" or "notok" values you can use map function:

```
val inpLst = List(1, 2, 2, 2, 1)
inpLst.map{
  case 1 => "ok"
  case 2 => "notok"
}
```

else if you need to have intermediate container in each time of processing list, you can use foldLeft:

```
inpLst.foldLeft(List.empty[String]){
  (buffer: List[String], i: Int) =>
    buffer ++ (i match {
      case 1 => List("ok")
      case 2 => List("notok")
    })
}
```

buffer will contain result of matching function on each previous iteration.